# Linker Error: Undefined reference to `ThreadPool::ThreadPool()'

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I have a class threadpool. I have a header file threadpool.h and the implementation threadpool.cc. When trying to I initialize the threadpool like so: `ThreadPool *tp = new ThreadPool();` I get the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libmapreducelib.a(mapreduce_impl.cc.o): in function `Master::Master(MapReduceSpec const&, std::vector<FileShard, std::allocator<FileShard> > const&)':
/aos-pr4/src/master.h:43: undefined reference to `ThreadPool::ThreadPool()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/mrdemo.dir/build.make:127: bin/mrdemo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:330: test/CMakeFiles/mrdemo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Here is my project source hierarchy:

```
src/
  >CMakeLists.txt
  >threadpool.h
  >threadpool.cc
  >otherfiles
CMakeLists.txt
```

Below is my threadpool.h, threadpool.cc and CMakeLists.txt file.

```cpp
// in theadpool.h
#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H
#pragma once
class ThreadPool {
    public:
        using Task = std::function<void()>;          
          
        // constructor, init static number of workers to be added to queue
        ThreadPool()
        ThreadPool(int numOfWorkers);
        virtual ~ThreadPool();
        ....
}
#endif
```

```cpp
// in threadpool.cc
#include "threadpool.h"
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(){
    // commented out
}
....
```

I even ensured my cmakelist library includes the threadpool.h.

```
//CMakeLists.txt
project(mapreducer)

include(GenerateProtos.cmake)

add_library(
  mapreducelib #library name
  mapreduce.cc mapreduce_impl.cc #sources
  master.h  mapreduce_spec.h file_shard.h threadpool.h) #headers
target_link_libraries(mapreducelib p4protolib)
target_include_directories(mapreducelib PUBLIC ${MAPREDUCE_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_dependencies(mapreducelib p4protolib)
```

I believe it should be fine and I've used my threadpool in another project. It must be the project hierarchy.

Comment: Now I'm not the greatest with cmake, but I'm not seeing threadpool.cc listed in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: `ThreadPool()` is missing a `;`.

Comment: Thank you. Both of those resolved my issue.